# I am trying to Google ARCore sceneform SDK in Xamarin Android. But I am getting error in "ModelRenderable.InvokeBuilder().SetSource()" method

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to Google ARCore sceneform SDK in Xamarin Android. But I am getting error:

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'no non-static method
>   "Lcom/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ModelRenderable$Builder;.setSource(Landroid/content/Context;I)Ljava/lang/Object;"'

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        if (!CheckIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(this))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        int requestPermissions=0;
        string cameraPermission = Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera;

        if (!(ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, cameraPermission) == (int)Permission.Granted))
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { cameraPermission, }, requestPermissions);
        }

        arFragment = (ArFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.ux_fragment);

        ModelRenderable.InvokeBuilder().SetSource(this, Resource.Raw.andy).Build(((renderable) =>
        {
            andyRenderable = renderable;

        }));

        //add the event handler
        arFragment.TapArPlane += OnTapArPlane;
```

Comment: Could you please further your explanation to the issue?

Comment: I am just trying to run this sample https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/SceneForm/samples

Comment: It seems you just cloned the project ran few times and reported it here. Update nugets and Android SDKs and retry. That should solve your issue

Comment: It seems, for newest android sdk and xamarin.sdk issue exists, maybe after updating sdk binding skip setSource method.
https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/833
Do anyone know, how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

You should try Java reflection... It works for me.

```
var builder = ModelRenderable.InvokeBuilder();
    
var javaClass = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(builder.GetType());
var method = javaClass.GetMethod("setSource", Class.FromType(renderableDefinition.GetType()));
method.Invoke(builder, renderableDefinition);

var future = builder.Build();
var model = future.Get();
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Matej Koncal's approach with reflection, you can find more examples on loading .sfb and .glb files on github discussion, here is the link https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/833#issuecomment-850443043